# Showing a flyoutmenu on a gridview item while Narrator is active

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, contextmenu, accessibility

I want to show a simple flyout menu on a gridviewitem. According to this article here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winuiautomation/2016/01/01/ten-questions-on-programmatic-accessibility/, (paragraph 6) you should be able to just set up a handler for the doubletapped event. I also tested it in the windows phone ui.

The problem is that ,in my app, the doubletap handler never gets called when doing the 2-finger double-tap gesture while narrator is activated.

I tried to do this in my gridview:

```
<GridView x:Name="ImgGrid" 
ItemsSource="{x:Bind AllFiles, Mode=OneWay}"
IsItemClickEnabled="True"
SelectionMode="None"
Background="{ThemeResource PaneBackgroundBrush}" Padding="8" 
ItemClick="ImgGrid_ItemClick"
ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemContainerStyle}"
IsDoubleTapEnabled="True"
DoubleTapped="ImgGrid_DoubleTapped">
```

As you can see, the doubletapped flag is enabled and there's a handler attached for the doubletapped event. But it doesn't get called with the 2-finger double tapped gesture. However, on non-mobile devices, the handler gets called by rightclicking on a gridview item.

I also tried to put the eventhandler on the gridviewitem itself:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="data:KNFBFileInfo">
   <Grid x:Name="ThumbnailContainer" 
         Margin="8" 
         Width="80" 
         Background="Transparent" 
         MinHeight="100" 
         Height="Auto" 
         Holding="ThumbnailContainer_Holding"
         RightTapped="ThumbnailContainer_RightTapped">
```

Same result as the first thing i tried...

It's really a shame that it's so hard for a developer to make 
his app accessible

Comment: Have you tried adding the handler in the DataTemplate Grid rather than the GridView itself, just like you've added the RightTapped handler?

Comment: Yes, the datatemplate doesn't have that property

Answer (score 0):

I just created a sample app with MenyFlyout inside `DataTemplate`

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="LastItems">  
    <Grid RightTapped="Grid_RightTapped">  
        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>  
            <MenuFlyout>  
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item1"/>  
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item2"/>  
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item3"/>  
            </MenuFlyout>  
        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>  
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ''}" Padding="10" Margin="10,0" />  
    </Grid>  
</DataTemplate>
```

And then `Grid_RightTapped` method is as follows.

```
private void Grid_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)  
{  
    FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;  
    if (element != null) FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(element);  
}
```

Doing this, When I Right Click on Non-Mobile Devices and LongPress on Items on Mobile Devices, Flyout Shows up with no issues.

Comment: Yeah but that's not the problem. The problem is that the menu should open with the 2-finger double tap when narrator is active. (it should happen automatically when the righttapped handler is attached)

Answer (score 0):

There is an official document about the ["Narrator"](https://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/accessibility/use-narrator-on-my-phone/). When we Double-tap with one finger, or Hold with one finger and tap with a second, it will activate primary action. It means we tap the item once without the "Narrator". So the `DoubleTapped` event will never be fired.

When we Double-tap with two fingers, it will show the context menu of the select control. We should be able to add the `RightTapped` to the `GridView`. When we Double-tap with two fingers, the `RightTapped` will be fired.

It seems we can not select the `GridViewItem` in the "Narrator" mode. If we add the `SelectionChanged` event to the GridView, when we double tap the `GridViewItem`, the `SelectionChanged` will never be fired.

Comment: So there's no way to select the gridviewitem, and that's why the contextmenu doesn't show? Is there any workaround?

Comment: @PrisonMike As I known, when we use the finger, we can not get point on the `GridViewItem`.